# indexOfObject in an NSMutableArray returning garbage value

Tags: iphone, ios

Trying to get index on an object in NSMutableArray. It is returning some garbage value, not getting why it is not returning index of particular item. Below is code i tried.

```
NSString *type = [dictRow valueForKey:@"type"];

if([arrSeatSel indexOfObject:type])
{
    NSUInteger ind = [arrSeatSel indexOfObject:type];
    [arrTotRows addObject:[arrSeatSel objectAtIndex:ind]];
}
```

type contains value "Gold". And arrSeatSel contains

```
 (
"Gold:0",
"Silver:0",
"Bronze:1"
```

How to check that. Please guide.

Comment: Is the garbage value "2147483647" by any chance?

Comment: Can you show your whole relevant data structure?

Comment: @0x7fffffff ya same exactly.

Comment: @iPhoneProgrammatically See Jeffery Thomas' answer and this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNotFound

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you are getting is `NSNotFound`. You are getting `NSNotFound` because `@"Gold"` is not equal to `@"Gold:0"`.

You should try the following

```
NSUInteger index = [arrSeatSel indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [obj hasPrefix:type];
}];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    [arrTotRows addObject:[arrSeatSel objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

`-indexOfObjectPassingTest:` is a running the following loop. NOTE: `/* TEST */` is some code that returns true when the correct index is found.

```
NSUInteger index = NSNotFound;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i) {
   if (/* TEST */) {
       index = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

In my first sample, `/* TEST */` is `[obj hasPrefix:type]`. The final for loop would look like.

```
NSUInteger index = NSNotFound;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [arrSeatSel count]; ++i) {
   if ([arrSeatSel[i] hasPrefix:type]) {
       index = i;
       break;
   }
}

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    [arrTotRows addObject:[arrSeatSel objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

I like `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:` better.

The `[obj hasPrefix:type]` part is just a different way to comparing strings. Read the [`-hasPrefix:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix%3a) doc for more details.

Hope that answers all your questions.

Comment: that i know but i need to apply this thing only, is it possible.

Comment: Tried even this way same result. NSUInteger ind = [arrSeatSel indexOfObject:@"Gold:0"];

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes storing data properly can solve lot of hazzle. If I guess correctly

`"Gold:0"` denotes a circle of type Gold an its count 0.

You can try to reformat that to an array of items.

Such as

```
[
    {
        "Type": "Gold",
        "Count": 0
    },
    {
        "Type": "Silver",
        "Count": 0
    },
    {
        "Type": "Bronze",
        "Count": 1
    }
]
```

And then using predicate to find the index

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type == %@",@"Gold"];
NSUInteger index = [types indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
}];
```

Comment: no you judged it wrong my friend it is the selection made of particular type.

Comment: @iPhoneProgrammatically I was just suggesting a way. Even if its selection it still holds rite. count denotes how many of those selection is in each circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this.

```
[arrSeatSel enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    // object - will be your "type"
    // idx - will be the index of your type.
}];
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading that correctly, you're saying that `arrSeatSel` contains three `NSString`s, `@"Gold:0"`, `@"Silver:0"`, and `@"Bronze:1"`, correct?

And then your `NSString* type` is basically `@"Gold"`

The first thing is `Gold` and `Gold:0` are different strings, and that's just for starter.

As you are searching for a string in the array, you should take each string out, and do a string matching, not just a comparison. What I'm saying is this:

```
NSString* str1 = @"This is a string";
NSString* str2 = @"This is a string";
if ( str1 == str 2 ) NSLog(@"Miracle does happen!")
```

The conditional would never be true even though both `NSString`s contain the same value, they are different object, thus are different pointers pointing to different blocks of memory.

What you should do here is a string matching, I will recommend `NSString`'s `hasPrefix:` method here, as it seems to fit your need.